# Watchdog "404 page not found" entries from spambot guessing urls

Tags: advertising, log-messages

Browsing through the watchdog list I found a lot of **page not found** entries with urls like:

```
http://example.com/wp/wp-trackback.php
http://example.com/phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php
http://example.com/flpurrbiao.html
http://example.com/gxksjgjrwk.html
```

What's best practice to stop these hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block them using these modules, study these and related modules for perfect working solution to your need :

http://drupal.org/project/httpbl

http://drupal.org/project/badbehavior

http://drupal.org/project/antispam (Apart from blocking comment spam, disables bot showing 403 error)

http://drupal.org/project/botcha

Install http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html and use Real Time Block Lists (RBLs)

And finally a free-service like http://www.cloudflare.com/features-security will get things working.

Answer (score 0):

I had watchdog spam logging issue for several months when I came to this post, and in my case by installing and activating **httpbl** has solved immediately the problem.